# Get an HTML Element after it is appended to the DOM by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have an rather simple problem that I'm not able to solve. I want to get an HTML Element `<input></input>` after I appended it to the DOM, because I want to add some css classes to its `<li></li>` parent element. I managed to get it working for the `<li></li>` elements that are natively located in my HTML file, but for the element that I added by appending it to the DOM I can't manage to get it done.

The general HTML structure is like that:

```
<section class="main">
        <input id="toggle-all" class="toggle-all" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
        <ul class="todo-list">
        <!-- These are here just to show the structure of the list items -->
        <!-- List items should get the class `editing` when editing and `completed` when marked as completed -->
        <li class="completed">
            <div class="view">
                <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
                <label>Taste JavaScript</label>
                <button class="destroy"></button>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="view">
                <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
                <label>Buy a unicorn</label>
                <button class="destroy"></button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I'm appending an element of the same `<li></li>` HTML structure as the `<li></li>` elements above by this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const todoInput = document.querySelector(".new-todo");
    const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
    todoInput.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === KEY_ENTER && todoInput.value !== "") {
            const liElementTodo = createTodoItem();
            todoList.appendChild(liElementTodo);
            clearInputContent(todoInput);
        }
    });
});
```

Then if I check the checkbox on that appended items I want to add some css classes to its parent `<li></li>` element which works for the 2 items that are present in the DOM after "DOMContentLoaded" is fired.
Following code is also placed in the Eventlistener for the "DOMContentLoaded" event:

```
inputCheckboxElements = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
for (const inputCheckboxElement of inputCheckboxElements) {
    inputCheckboxElement.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
        const parentDivElement = inputCheckboxElement.parentElement;
        const parentLiElement = parentDivElement.parentElement;
        console.log(inputCheckboxElement);
        if (inputCheckboxElement.checked) {
            checkBoxToggled(parentLiElement);
        } else {
            checkBoxToggled(parentLiElement);
        }
    });
}
```

I thought I'd be able to somehow get all elements also those I appended by javascript with an MutationObserver but that didn't work out for me.
It would be cool if someone could help me out a bit.

Edit:
The MutationObserver object looks like that:

```
    MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
    var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
        console.log(mutations, observer);
        inputCheckboxElements = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
        console.log(inputCheckboxElements);
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true,
        childList: true
    });
```

Comment: Which element is your MutationObserver watching?

Comment: It was observing the document object.

Comment: I had an issue doing that. I used document.body with config childList and subTree set to true.

Comment: I tried it out with document.body but it still seems that it's not working for me. I added the MutationObserver code in my edit above.